# Pixel distortion after waking PC from sleep

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, sleep, pixels

I've had this really really weird issue for the past 6 months, and the case is starting to turn cold for me, so i better be asking you guys for help.

When waking a PC from sleep, one display with experience pixel distortion until i reboot the PC. 
The issue looks like this:

[This is what the issue looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgpYa.jpg)

Something to help the troubleshoot:
- It's not related to GPU, i've switched multiple times with no result.

- The issue is occuring to multiple users in my company (3 by the time i write this)
- Switching all cables doesn't help anything,
- Unplug-in/plug-in cables, will leave the monitor out of use as it can't reestablish the connection.
- The issue is not related to a manufacturer in any way. It has occured on different custom build machine, dell machine, hp monitors, and dell monitors.
- All machine are running Windows 1709 or later
- The issue has been seen on various Nvidia drivers, from 369.xxx to 417.xxx
- Performing a clean installation of Windows doesn't help anything.
- Switching monitors doesn't help anything
- There is no connection between the different PC's besides the domain. Based in different departments, the use and installations of the PC's vary a lot.
- Pulling the power chord from the monitor while the issue occurs and holding down the power button for 60 seconds doesn't help anything

Only workaround so far, is changing the display settings to "show only 1 display" and back to "expand dispalys" in windows, this will only help sometimes (30% of instances)

I'll gladly try out whatever solution you come up with, as this issue is starting to make me crazy!

If something is an electrician, perhaps they can help me out if it's related to this?

Comment: I've used lots of times searching the internet for similar scenarios, and all i can find is 1 person where it looks like the case has gone cold too....

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-aniversary-pixelated-screen/8e09b5de-0e75-43c8-9780-71e1d1de8e17

Comment: I've been showing the picture to a LED Engineer to see if he could recognize the issue, this is what he said: 

"It looks like a scenario, where fx. an laptops internal monitor is shown underneath the external monitor, as if you chose to duplicate the displays wrongfully.

Things like this often happens if you choose a custom sized LED, for example 3000x1500 and are running windows in 1920x1080 - if so, issues like this are known to occur."


As it is right now, i'm running 2560x1440 on both displays, which is native for both of them.